# scrapy RuntimeError: To use XPath or CSS selectors, ItemLoader be instantiated with a selector

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-item

I have an `ProductItemlLoader` which is just a simple `ItemlLoader` that loads into a simple `ProductItem` with an `offer_type` field

I run this code:

```
il = ProductItemLoader(response=response)
il.add_css('offer_type', '.incentive-type-label')
```

and recieve:
`RuntimeError: To use XPath or CSS selectors, ItemLoader be instantiated with a selector`

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

The more concise way of declaring ItemLoader is the following :

`item = ItemLoader(item=ProductItem(), selector=response)`

If you cycle through a loop of a broader selector :

```py
sel = response.xpath('//xpath/selection')    # return a list of Selectors

for one_product in sel:
    item = ItemLoader(item=ProductItem(), response=response, selector=one_product)
    # item populating
    # yielding the item
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I had this code running on scrapy 1.4 and I now moved to scrapy 2.3 .

In the old version it worked fine but now, in order to make use of selectors I had to add some lines and remove old ones.

So instead of this:
`il = ProductItemLoader(response=response)`

I now needed to do this:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

selector = Selector(response=response, type='html')
il = AudiDealItemLoader(selector=selector)
```

reference from the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector)